# Format for connecting to rackspace via CyberDuck CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, rackspace-cloud, cyberduck

I'm struggling to get a simple test of the cyberduck cli working from my computer to rackspace. Looking at the how-to (https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/cli) it shows this as the format: `rackspace://<container>/<key>.`

The test I am doing is as follows:

```
duck -username my_username -password my_api_key --list rackspace://test/my_api_key
```

"test" is a directory in the CDN off of the root. Trying this generates this message:
Interoperability failure. Java.lang.NullPointerException. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.

I've also tried: `duck -username my_username -password my_api_key --list rackspace://test/`

and received the same results.

What is the correct formatting? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running Cyberduck CLI version 6.6.0 (28133)?

Comment: `<container>` refers to a top level container in your Rackspace account and `<key>` refers to a directory or file in that container.

Comment: I know its a little off topic but I've had a lot of success with [turbolift](https://github.com/cloudnull/turbolift) working with RAX CDN / files.